# Confirming deletion of record in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, confirm

I m trying to delete a row in php mysql. The row is deleted quiet ok but `mysqli_affected_rows($conn)` is not giving a response so I can confirm the deletion for the user.

```
 $sql="DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `memberID`='$id'";
 $res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($conn) == 1){
     echo 'success'
 } else {
     echo "The User could not be deleted due to some error";
     echo mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
 }
```

Comment: Are you certain memberID are unique?  If not you need to change `==` with `>0`.

Comment: `echo 'success'` is missing the `;`

Comment: you can call model when click delete button. so when you click on YES from model you could perform delete.

Comment: Does your PHP error log state any errors?

Comment: Thanx for the comments. yes memberID is unique. av also corrected echo 'succee';  unfortunetly no erros are output but the record is deteted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to check by boolean value 0 or 1. But if you want to do it that way, you will need to declare a flag before that and then change the flag value according to condition after that you can do it [as your way]

> (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) == 1)

But as default a simple `if()` conditon will check and return true on pass and false on fail.

So, simply you can do:

```
if($res)
{
//your codes if query is done
} else
{
//your codes if query fails
}
```

Comment: unfortunately its not working as well. could it be that am using php7?

Comment: I found my problem. I am using JavaScript(ajax)  so my code for output in java script had a wrong logic and that is why i was getting wrong feedback. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

By default, the mysqli_query() function will return you a true if all went well or a false if there is any error. You can check if your query did not return any error like so:

```
if($res) {
   echo "Delete success";
} else {
    echo "Delete error: " . mysqli_error();
}
```

Comment: i don't know why but its not working ... its still showing me error message in the else. it deletes the data